# Return from redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

How can i redirect user in filter to another action and remember action which he wanted to do before redirect and repeat it after he do any action on that redirected page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the filter:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var dictionary = new RouteValueDictionary();
    dictionary["action"] = "newaction";
    dictionary["controller"] = "home";
    dictionary["returnUrl"] = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(dictionary);
}
```

And then use the `returnUrl` parameter in the new action.